# Block DMZ to get Access to Internet and LAN

Tags: nat, acl

why my external DMZ can always connect to Internet then i want not the DMZ has access to Internet and sub network(Informatique and Administration). What's wrong in my config.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you are trying to do.  Can you explain it again?

Comment: Ok i have an external DMZ which connect to Internet and i want to deny this connection. I tried some ACL but it blocks all traffic instead the only i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try again, now that I think I understand your requirements better.
I think you want to allow inbound connections to the DMZ, but deny outbound connections from the DMZ

```
ip access-list extended Deny-Outbound
permit tcp any any established
permit icmp any any echo-reply

interface fa 0/0
ip access-group Deny-Outbound in
```

If this isn't what you want, please help me understand better.

Comment: Thanks you very much it work. So i have a question about these 2 words established and echo-reply, they are keywords or just a name you take ? I'm not yet familiar with the ACL.

Comment: They are keywords.  "Established" only permits tcp packets with the ACK flag set.  A new connection doesn't have that flag set, so it will be blocked.  "Echo-reply" only allows responses to pings (echo-request).  So you can ping the DMZ, but the DMZ can't ping out.

Comment: I forget to ask you something about Radius Server, is it possible to block that server for some user of sub network ? I tried one like this but it doesn't work: access-list 101 deny udp 192.168.40.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 eq 1645